# DJANGO - How do you access the current model instance from inside a form

Tags: python, django, model, instance

```
class EditAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = username.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), initial=???)
```

You can see what I'm trying to do here. How would I go about pre-populating the pasword_confirm field (which is not part of the model). I'm so confused.

Comment: What would like you like to populate the field with?

Comment: You've declared the password field twice, I assume you meant for the first field to be username. Password confirmation is also something that I can only think of as being user-added, rather than automatically pre-populated. I am having a hard time imagining your use case.  Feel free to add more information about what exactly you're trying to do and maybe we can help you.

Comment: I am also curious what you want to populate  password_confirm with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the instance in the form declaration, because there isn't one until you instantiate it.

However, if all you want to do is set dynamic initial data, do this with the `initial` parameter on instantation:

```
form = EditAdminForm(initial={'password':'abcdef'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `__init__` method in EditAdminForm.

something like:

```
class EditAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    def __init__(self, initial_from, data=None, initial=None)
        sefl.fields['password_confirm'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), initial=initial_from)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer too. I didn't try because I was a bit confused, but going forward I don't think I want that coupled with the form itself because then if I use the form without an instance, it'll throw an error.